# Toggle Relative Layout visibility with Radio Buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have run into a weird problem:
I have been making my first android app - a simple bodyfat calculator. One of the features requires that if the user selects his gender as "Male" then the layout, which requires to enter hip circumference should get invisible. And vice versa. The problem is, when the "Male" radio button is checked, the layout indeed disappears, but when a "Female" radio button is checked, the view doesn't come back! Why?
[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKuOg.jpg)

```
     genderGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            calculator.setGender(radioButton.getText().toString());
            Log.d("log", radioButton.getText().toString());
            if(radioButton.getText() == "Female"){
                hip_layout.setAlpha(0.0f);
            }
           else{
                hip_layout.setAlpha(1.0f);
            }
            toaster(calculator.getGender());
        }
    });
```

Comment: hip_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) / hip_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: where is getCheckedRadioButtonId() ?

Comment: I have also figured out that mistakenly I used the '==', instead of .equals()
It all works now! Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the radio buttons selected and set set visibility accordingly

```
genderGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                for (int rb_index=0;rb_index<genderGroup.getChildCount();rb_index++)
                {
                    Log.e("RADIOBUTTON :",""+rb_index+"/"+genderGroup.getChildCount());

                    RadioButton rb=((RadioButton) genderGroup.getChildAt(rb_index));
                    if(rb.isChecked()&&rb.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("male")){
                        Log.e("RADIOBUTTON :"," OK "+rb_index);

                         hip_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                      if(rb.isChecked()&&rb.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("female")){

                          hip_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }


            }
        });
```

for your layout :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rdg"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="male"
        android:text="Male"/>
 <RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/female"
     android:tag="female"

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"/>
</RadioGroup>
```